# Is this a valid proof of Borsuk-Ulam Theorem, assuming Brouwer's Theorem?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, algebraic-topology

I'm wondering if I went wrong in this proof, and if so where. I consider a continuous map $f: S^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, and by continuity the set $f(S^n)$ is compact and connected in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now assume for now that this set is in fact homotopy-equivalent to $B_1(0)$, the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then consider the map which sends $f(x) \in f(S^n)$ to $f(-x) \in f(S^n)$. This map is continuous and maps the aforementioned compact set (homotopy-equivalent to a closed ball) to itself. Then Brouwer's theorem applies, guaranteeing a fixed point of the map, i.e. f(x) = f(-x).

Then I justify the claim of homotopy equivalence by saying that the map $f: S^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ induces a homomorphism between the homology groups of the respective spaces, and $S^n$ only has nontrivial $H^n$ (but $\mathbb{R}^n$ has trivial $H^n$) so we have the aforementioned compact sets having all homology groups trivial (so the set is contractible).

This proof seems too sketchy to work, so please criticize all the errors you see.

Comment: For a start, $f(S^n)$ need not be homotopy equivalent to a ball.

Comment: What's an example of such an $f(S^n)$?

Comment: @Marcus:  Map $S^n$ to an interval, then wrap the interval into a circle.  In terms of explicitly writing such a function, try $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n+1}) = (\cos(x_1),\sin(x_1),0,0,...,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! This clearly means my proof fails. I guess I better keep going.